# Removing ArrayList elements inside synchronized method

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a `synchronized` method that operates over an `ArrayList` and then removes its elements, by calling `ArrayList.clear()`.

Why am I getting `ConcurrentModificationException` when multiple threads call this method, even though it is synchronized?

Isn't the keyword `synchronized` used to avoid this kind of errors?

```
public MyOuterClass {

  private class MyInnerClass implements MyCallback {

    private class MyInnermostClass implements Runnable {

      @Override
      public void run() {

        if (condition) {
          myMethod();
        }
        else {
          synchronized (myArrayList) {
            myArrayList.add(new MyObject());
          }
      }
    }

    public void myCallback() {
      Thread myThread = new Thread(new MyInnermostClass());
      myThread.start();
    }
  }

  private ArrayList<MyObject> myArrayList;

  public MyClass() {
    myArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  private synchronized void myMethod() {
    for (MyObject o: myArrayList) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
    myArrayList.clear();
  }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:893)
    at my.package.MyOuterClass.myMethod(MyOuterClass.java:myLineNumber)
```

Comment: Is that all the code? or do you do other things inside the for loop like adding/removing/modifying elements?

Comment: Please post the stack trace and your actual code. Usually `ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do with threading (although multithreading can aggravate the problem). It comes from modifying the list while an iterator is still actively iterating the list. The code you posted will not generate that exception; something else is going on (probably having nothing to do with `synchronized`).

Comment: agreed, that code won't cause the described Exception to be raised

Comment: There has to be a code where you may be modifying the List , since the xception is related to concurrentModification

Comment: Check either you are modifying a final list or if its not final you must use Iterator to modify the value as the block is synchronized the code will work fine. Do let us know the issues or full stack trace or some part of code you missed to put here.

Comment: @Bentaye I've edited my post with the details you asked.

Comment: @TedHopp I've edited my post with the details you asked.

Comment: @amRika I've edited my post with the details you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your method is being called from multiple threads, it definitely needs to be synchronized. However, it sounds like something else is going on.

Despite its name, `ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do (inherently) with thread concurrency. Instead, it is thrown when an iterator notices that the collection over which it is iterating was changed in some unexpected way. For instance, the following will generate a `ConcurrentModificationException`, even with a single-thread application:

```
for (Object o : myArrayList) {
    if (shouldRemove(o)) {
        myArrayList.remove(o);
    }
}
```

The correct way to handle that situation is to use an explicit iterator and use it to remove elements:

```
for (Iterator<Object> iter = myArrayList.iterator(), Object o;
        iter.hasNext();
        o = iter.next())
{
    if (shouldRemove(o)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

You can also use `ListIterator` (obtained with `myArrayList.listIterator()`) to gain a bit more control of the list contents while iterating (such as replacing an element).

The reason your method needs to be `synchronized` is that otherwise one thread might call `myArrayList.clear()` while another thread is still iterating, causing an exception. There's also the possibility that simultaneous calls to `myArrayList.clear()` could corrupt the internal structure of the list.

Since your method is synchronized, I suspect that you have one (or both) of these problems:

1. you are concurrently modifying the list on another thread in some other code that you haven't posted;
2. you are doing something (other than calling `System.out.println(o)`) within the body of the `for` loop that is modifying the list.

Either of those would cause the exception. For the first problem, you need to ensure that *every piece of code* that modifies `myArrayList` is synchronized. Not only that, they need to be synchronized on the same object. For the second problem, either arrange your code to do the list modifications after the iterator is done or else use an explicit iterator and make all changes using that.

**EDIT** Based on your edited question, here's my diagnosis: you are synchronizing different blocks of code on different objects, so you are still executing code concurrently on multiple threads. Specifically, in `MyInnermostClass`, you are synchronizing on `myArrayList`. In `MyClass`, it's the `myMethod()` itself that is synchronized, which synchronizes on the instance of `MyClass`, not on the array. The best thing to do, I think, is to redefine `myMethod()` as follows:

```
private void myMethod() {
    synchronized (myArrayList) {
        for (MyObject o: myArrayList) {
            System.out.println(o);
        }
        myArrayList.clear();
    }
}
```

That way, all the code that modifies `myArrayList` is synchronized on the list object itself.

Comment: @Tirafesi - I  updated my answer now that I have more info.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you :D